# get lat long from maps and displayed it to text box in java script

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i make google maps autocomplete address textbox to get latitude and longitude without map by using google.maps.places.Autocomplete class we can implement Google places autocomplete textbox and display selected address latitude and longitude details

I've tried like this

```
<!-- add library script -->
                            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed in=true&libraries=places"></script>
                            <!-- logig to auto complete the address -->
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intilize);
                                function intilize() {
                                    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("txtautocomplete"));

                                    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

                                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                                    var location = "Address: " + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
                                    location += "Latitude: " + place.geometry.location.lat() + "<br/>";
                                    location += "Longitude: " + place.geometry.location.lng();
                                    document.getElementById('lblresult').innerHTML = location
                                    });

                                };

                                </script>

                                <span>location:</span><input type="text" id="txtautocomplete" style="width:200px" placeholder="enter the adress"/>
                                <label id="lblresult"></label>
```

but it didn't work for me, the autocomplete address didn't show please help me

Comment: try http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/custom_attribute.html